# Playwright's "await locator.click()" fails with timeout. Why?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm writing an Electron app to scrape a web page using Playwright. I can successfully make my way through three sequential page requests, but can't get the field I need on the third page. The css selectors I've tried do not find the field. I'm new to Playwright so I've experimented a lot. I discovered the Locator, and that was able to find the field. The pattern I use is copied from the Playwright library documents:

```
const locator = page.locator('id="focus-input"');
await locator.click();
```

The first statement creates a locator with this content:

```
_frame:Frame {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0, _connection: Connection, _parent: BrowserContext, …}
_channel:Proxy {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: undefined, _object: Frame, Symbol(kCapture): false}
_childFrames:Set(2) {size: 2, Frame {_events, …}, Frame {…}}
_connection:Connection {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 1, _maxListeners: undefined, _objects: Map(511), _waitingForObject: Map(0), …}
_csi:undefined
_detached:false
_eventEmitter:EventEmitter {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: 0, Symbol(kCapture): false}
_events:{}
_eventsCount:0
_guid:'frame@e0bbdb6106bf77e2c8a15b4d4d90ee26'
_initializer:{url: 'about:blank', name: '', parentFrame: undefined, loadStates: Array(0)}
_loadStates:Set(2) {size: 2, domcontentloaded, load}
_logger:undefined
_maxListeners:0
_name:''
_objects:Map(0) {size: 0}
_page:Page {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 2, _maxListeners: 0, _connection: Connection, _parent: BrowserContext, …}
_selector:'id="focus-input"'
[[Prototype]]:Object
```

The second statement times out:

```
name:'TimeoutError'
message:'locator.click: Timeout 30000ms exceeded.
```

The HTML segment with the field I want is this input component with id="focus-input":

```
<input _ngcontent-c1="" aria-autocomplete="list" autocomplete="off" class="search-box mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="focus-input" matinput="" role="combobox" style="text-transform:uppercase" type="search" aria-expanded="false" aria-owns="mat-autocomplete-0" placeholder="Search Ticker or Company" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="false">
```

Why won't this work for me?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue with your selector.

It should be:

```js
//                                ↓ without quotes
const locator = page.locator('id=focus-input');
```

or it also could be:

```js
const locator = page.locator('#focus-input');
```

Comment: I tried it with both of your suggestions. Neither one worked. Still get the timeout.

Comment: @MartinDuo, are you sure that the element with the specified id is visible and present on the page? Try to add `waitFor` method before clicking it `await locator.waitFor();`.

Comment: The real problem is that an iFrame was loaded as part of the last page.goto(url) request. The selectors are not searching the correct page. By searching the page content using the page.content() request, the src=url code can be found and that url can be used in the last page.goto(url) request to go directly to the iframe holding the needed html fields. I found this tip: https://testautomationu.applitools.com/js-playwright-tutorial/chapter3.5.html